# React native create polygon shapes

Tags: react-native, polygon

I am pretty new to react native, and I want to create a weirdly shaped Hexagon. I tried looking up how I would do that, but the only things I could find are examples of polygons made on google maps. And I am not interested in that.

This is an example of the kinda polygon I want to add in my app:

[image]

this would is the css of the polygon:

```
clip-path: polygon(36% 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 64% 100%, 0 100%, 0 45%);
```

How can I create this polygon in react native?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This link is extremely impressive. I have not used it personally, but check out and let us know if this helps.
https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native